# getDrawable with AnimatedVectorDrawable crashes in android version 4

Tags: android

I tried to access AnimatedVectorDrawable as follows using the ContextCompat. Im using the following code to do so. It works well in Android version 5 and above but not in android version 4.

```
@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
    private void startOpenAnimations() {

        // Icon
        AnimatedVectorDrawable menuIcon = (AnimatedVectorDrawable) ContextCompat.getDrawable(getContext(),
                R.drawable.ic_menu_animated);
        mFabView.setImageDrawable(menuIcon);
        menuIcon.start();

        // Reveal
        int centerX = mFabRect.centerX();
        int centerY = mFabRect.centerY();
        float startRadius = getMinRadius();
        float endRadius = getMaxRadius();
        Animator reveal = ViewAnimationUtils
                .createCircularReveal(mNavigationView,
                        centerX, centerY, startRadius, endRadius);

        // Fade in
        mNavigationMenuView.setAlpha(0);
        Animator fade = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(mNavigationMenuView, View.ALPHA, 0, 1);

        // Animations
        AnimatorSet set = new AnimatorSet();
        set.playSequentially(reveal, fade);
        set.start();
    }
```

> android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: File
>   res/drawable/ic_menu_animated.xml from drawable resource ID
>
> ## 0x7f020064
>
> ```
>                                                                     at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:3451)
>                                                                     at android.content.res.Resources.getDrawable(Resources.java:1894)
>                                                                     at
> ```
>
> android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat.getDrawable(ContextCompat.java:354)

why is that getDrawable with ContextCompat is not possible in Lollipop devices

How can I be able to sort this out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this : `AnimatedVectorDrawableCompat.create(this, R.drawable.animated_vector_name)`

Reference:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/35699072/7001152

Comment: but the xml file works well with animatedvectordrawable